# Show ampersand in Elementor widget in Text Control

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I used the following code in Text Control in the development of a custom Elementor widget:

```
esc_html__( '&', 'textdomain' );
```

The ampersand sign is not shown in the output.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: you need to echo it out. `echo esc_html__( '&', 'textdomain' );`

Comment: How to echo in widget elementor?